# Take text from string and render it as bold in Material-Table

Tags: javascript, material-table

The following code looks for the comma in a string and replaces it with a line break.

```
render: (rowData) => (
    <>
        {rowData.Taxonomy.split(", ").map((b) => {
            return (
                <>
                    {b},
                    <br />
                </>
            );
        })}
    </>
),
```

The output into a material-table looks like this:

Domain: Corporate,
DomainLeader: John Doe,

How can I adapt this code to make `Domain` and `DomainLeader` bold?:

**Domain:** Corporate,
**DomainLeader:** John Doe,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use material v5 you can:
I assumed ":" is fixed char and the rest chars are dynamic

```js
 <Box sx={{ display:"flex", flexDirection: 'column' }}>
    {rowData.Taxonomy.split(", ").map((b) => (
                <Box sx={{ display:"flex" }}>
                    <Box sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                        {b.split(':')[0]}:
                    </Box>
                    <Box>&nbsp;{b.split(':')[1]},</Box>
                </Box>    
            ))}
    </Box>
```

Comment: Changing `<Box sx={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>` to `<Box sx={{ display: "flex"}}>` gives the desired outcome in your answer.  Thank you for your help

Comment: How would you change this to make all characters between `,` and `:` bold without goin to a new line so the output would look like this: ***Domain:*** Corporate, ***DomainLeader:*** John Doe.

The incoming data from JSON looks like this: `"details" : "Domain: Corporate, DomainLeader: John, Doe, ........"`

Comment: it is enough to remove  ```flexDirection: 'column' ``` from the first line